# multiple use of jade block mixin in one template

Tags: pug, block, mixins

I am pretty new to jade and I have the following problem.
Having this (simplified) mixin:

```
mixin someMixin()
   .someClass 
      block first
   .otherClass 
      block second
```

now I try to you this mixin multiple times in one template. Like this.

```
+someMixin()
   block first
      div First Block of first Mixin
   block second
      div Second Block of first Mixin

+someMixin()
   block first
      div First Block of second Mixin
   block second
      div Second Block of second Mixin
```

as a result only the blocks of the first mixin are used. Like this

```
<div class="someClass">First Block of first Mixin</div>
<div class="otherClass">Second Block of first Mixin</div>

<div class="someClass">First Block of first Mixin</div>
<div class="otherClass">Second Block of first Mixin</div>
```

I was expecting a result like this:

```
<div class="someClass">First Block of first Mixin</div>
<div class="otherClass">Second Block of first Mixin</div>

<div class="someClass">First Block of second Mixin</div>
<div class="otherClass">Second Block of second Mixin</div>
```

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance.

Amiroo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From http://jade-lang.com/reference/inheritance/:

> A block is simply a "block" of Jade that may be replaced within a
>   child template.

If you want to use different data in mixin, use variables:

```
mixin someMixin(a, b)
    div.someClass #{a}
    div.otherClass #{b}

+someMixin("1-1", "1-2")
+someMixin("2-1", "2-2")
```

Result:

```
<div class="someClass">1-1</div>
<div class="otherClass">1-2</div>
<div class="someClass">2-1</div>
<div class="otherClass">2-2</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

With credit to [nekitk on Codepen.io](https://codepen.io/nekitk/pen/bdMZgb?editors=1000), here's a technique that neatly sidesteps the single-block limitation:

```
// initialization
- blocks = {}

mixin set(key)
  - blocks[key] = this.block

// mixin definition
mixin layout
  block
  .main
    - blocks.main()
  .side
    - blocks.side()

// mixin call
+layout
  +set('main')
    p Main
  +set('side')
    p Side
```

Comment: This is really useful! Adittionally, making these additional blocks optional is also useful: `if blocks.main ...`. That way you could make mixins (i.e. components) that are usable in flexible ways

Comment: Sadly this does force you to always have to set both 'main' and 'side'. If you create a second 'layout' block and add only the 'side' block then it will copy the block of the first instance (example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gzXRre?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that doesn't have the weaknesses that @Remi mentioned.
https://codepen.io/Vectorjon/pen/GRmYWjN

```
mixin block(key, marker=false)
    - global.my_blocks = global.my_blocks || {}
    if marker
        if global.my_blocks[key]
            - let temp = {}
            - temp[key] = global.my_blocks[key]
            - global.my_blocks[key] = null
            - temp[key]()
        else
            block
    else
        - global.my_blocks[key] = this.block
```

Quick overview on usage:

```
mixin example
    block
    .part-1
        +block('one', true)
            p one's default
    .part-2
        +block('two', true)

+example
    +block('one')
        p whatever
        p you
        p want
    +block('two')
        p also
        p whatever
```

Hope you find it useful. Comment on my [CodePen](https://codepen.io/Vectorjon/pen/GRmYWjN)  if you find any bugs or have suggestions.